# Fancybox change rel when user agent == iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, fancybox

I want to change the rel attribute of the fancybox when agent == iphone & ipod because
the fancybox does not work on a iphone. The frame is very small and the video is unviewable. I am using fancybox with magento on a category page.

When a user on a iphone clicks on "click me" the video should open on the normal youtube page otherwise ( on a computer ) the fancybox should appear as normal.

I tried the following code but it does not work.

Is there an other solution.

Code: http://pastebin.com/1aEU1xad

Answer (score 0):

From your code, why you don't try initializing fancybox if `agentID` **IS NOT** `iPhone/iPod`?

... something like :

```
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod)/);
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    // only initialize fancybox if agentID IS NOT iPhone/iPod
    if (!agentID) {
        jQuery("a[rel=fancybox]").fancybox({
            // API options
        })
    }
});
```